# how to correctly remote-debug a pod with intellij?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, kubernetes

when i'm connecting to remote-debug port to a pod (openshift) using intellij how can i prevent from the pod to crash and the debug session to stop and keep the debug alive ?  ( like in eclipse )  .

this is a pod running under openshift platform . when connecting to remote debug withe the same configuration and same port using eclipse the debug session is not terminating and the pod is not crashing .

the command line arguments : 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=45288
Debugger mode : Attach to remote VM

Comment: How is it crashing?

Comment: the pod is not responding for couple of minutes and the debug session is stopped and released . @NeplatnyUdaj

Comment: I'd recommend to create a support ticket for Intellij team: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?intellij-idea with the idea.log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) and thread dumps attached: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-doesn-t-respond .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Suspend policy: Thread* when debugging. As per [Breakpoint properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties) docs:

> Thread: only the thread containing this breakpoint will be suspended.

This approach is far from ideal. If you are debugging a multi-threaded application other threads will continue to run and potentially interfere with your debugging session. However it might allow the pod to pass the liveness test.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know maybe why in eclipse it is working well ? @Karol Dowbecki

Comment: This should has nothing to do with IDE, both Eclipse and IntelliJ use the same JVM debugging interface when connecting to remote JVM. Most likely settings are different in Eclipse.